# How to identify a user who will always have the same ID in the same computer?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

A system I'm developing tracks the products that are taken from a warehouse

---

Example:
`User A`, takes the `product Z`, and the `user B` is the one that inputs this in the database, a simplified version of this situation would look as follows in the db:

```
+------------+----------+------------+
| Id_Product | Id_taker | Id_inputs  |
+------------+----------+------------+
|      Z     |    A     |    B       |
-------------+----------+------------+
```

This web app assumes that `person B` always uses the same computer (user requirement), so every time a user who inputs the information of a product that is going to be taken, completes the form, I would like the ID of the person (who is already in the database) to be implicit, and not ask this person to enter his own ID every time.

There are a couple of things that the user can input and I always need to identify that user, so in the web app if he or she clicks "upload something", and taken to that page, when filling the fields I never want the user to input his own ID (that would be ridiculous), still, I need to know the person's ID.

---

How can I accomplish this in an elegant way?

Comment: Maybe a cookie would work for this

Comment: What kind of authentication is the application using? Can't you use their login information to do it?

Comment: @itsme86 They are not logging in to the system, they just have a link to use the system in the computer. Today there are only two individuals using it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly how would you implement this using a cookie?

Comment: You can get the user name from the environmental variables on the machine.

Comment: @jdweng It's an asp.net application, presumably on a computer that's not the same one the user is using. Maybe that's a false assumption on my part.

Comment: You are using ASP.Net so you have a client and server.  When you connect to a server the html file is downloaded to client and run in a browser on client machine.  So the environmental variables are on the client.  Once the environmental variables are read you can send to server if needed.  But most cases the ASP.NET is running on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a txt file that has the id of the user in the database. For every new user (there won't be any, as far as I've been told by the user) I would have to give them a copy of the app, and the id in a txt file. Not my proudest moment, but it works.